# scp all git modified file using single command to another server

Tags: linux, git, scp, cp

I am trying to copy multiple files which I had changed, to a new server.

For this I followed the steps:

```
git status
scp filename server
```

The above steps I had to repeat multiple time, can I write a single command to do `git status` and then copy all the modified files to the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check first if `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=AM` would give you the right list (for added/modified files currently in the working tree, not yet added to the index)

If so, you could do

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=AM | xargs -I '{}' scp '{}' server
```